# Symfony form state backup to database and restore / or: how to prepopulate a form from database

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a big form with time, date, select and EntityType fields in it. The form is not linked to an entity, but it do contain fields from other entities. In other words I have no `data_class` in the OptionsResolver of the FormType.

Here is my formtype: (showing just one field for simplicity)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
        $builder
            ->add('company', EntityType::class, array(
                'placeholder' => 'Companies',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Company',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'required' => false
            ))
            //... much more fields
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    // This form is not linked to an Entity
    // Therefore no `data_class`
}
```

In the controller I can backup the data of a form. Called a FormState. I save a FormState to the database as follows:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    /** // ... */
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ReportType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // Save the form to a FormState
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->getClickedButton()->getName() == 'saveFormState') {
            $formStateManager = $this->get('app.manager.form_state');

            // Get form data that we want to save
            $data = $form->getData();
            $name = 'Stackoverflow example'; // give it a name

            $formState = $formStateManager->createNewFormState(); // Create new FormState Entity object
            $formState->setName( $name );
            $formState->setData( $data );
            $formStateManager->save( $formState );
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

All this above works perfect. But now the tricky part, I have to set the backupdata back to the form. The user can select a previous form state from a list of FormStates. And then hit the load button.

The `data` attribute of a FormState object I try to  load into the form is just a `$form->getData()` result. Thus a normal array without objects. Maybe that is the problem, but I can't get it to work whatsoever.

That `data` array is what I trying to load into the form so it takes its values over. I tried it via `$form->setData()`, or by creating a new form with `$this->createForm(ReportType::class, $data)`. Both fail with the same error message: `Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?`.

---

I have tried two ways of adding the data:

**First try, in controller:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    /** // ... */
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->getClickedButton()->getName() == 'loadFormState') {
            // ...

            $form = $this->createForm(ReportType::class, $formState->getData()); // <-- throws the error
            $form->submit($formState->getData());
        }
    }

}
```

**Second try, via FormEvent subscriber:**
When I do it via a FormEvent subscriber, like below, I get the same error. Here is my code:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\EventListener;

class ReportFieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    // ...

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => array(
                array('loadFormState'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Load selected FormState in form
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function loadFormState(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        //...   
        // Choosen FormState
        $formState = $formStateManager->findOneById($formStateId);

        $formStateData = $formState->getData();

        $form->setData($formStateData); // <-- Set data, trows error
        // ...
    }
}
```

As I said both solutions throwing the error: `Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?`

What is the preferred solution in this case? I can create a dummy Entity, and fix this problem, but it feels a bit ugly and not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

After days of fiddling I found the solution.

My struggles where **not** how to save form data, as I showed in the question. However, I made a mistake by saving **view data** to the database and trying to load that later. Have a good read here for what I mean: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#registering-event-listeners-or-event-subscribers

So, I also rewrite the saving of a form state to be in the form subscriber. *Note: remember my form has no `data_class` in the OptionsResolver settings of the FormType. So there is no auto datamapping and such.*

In my initial question, you can see I have multiple submit buttons, and in the controller you can check which one was clicked easily. Because in the controller you have access to the `getClickedButton()` function. But not in the form subscriber. So I found a way to get the clicked button in the EventSubscriberInterface of the form:

```
class ReportFieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * Find which button was clicked
     * @param $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClickedButton($data)
    {
        $requestParams = serialize($data);

        if (strpos($requestParams, 'saveFormState') !== false) {
            return 'saveFormState';
        }
        if (strpos($requestParams, 'loadFormState') !== false) {
             return 'loadFormState';
        }
        if (strpos($requestParams, 'deleteFormState') !== false) {
             return 'deleteFormState';
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Below  you find the actual solution how I saved and loadedthe form the right way. I hook them up in the FormEvent::PRE_SUBMIT stage. At that stage you can save and load **[Request data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#registering-event-listeners-or-event-subscribers)** into the FormEvent. Perfect.

**Saving and loading/prepopulating the form data via FormEvent::PRE_SUBMIT:**

```
class ReportFieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => array(
                array('saveFormState'),
                array('loadFormState'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Save form data
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function saveFormState(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        if ($this->getClickedButton($data) == 'saveFormState') {
            $formStateManager = $this->formStateManager;

            // ...
            $formState = $formStateManager->createNewFormState();
            // ...

            $formState->setData($data);
            $formStateManager->save($formState);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load choosen form data
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function loadFormState(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();

        if ($this->getClickedButton($data) == 'loadFormState') {
            $formStateId = $data['formState']['formStates'];

            if (is_numeric($formStateId)) {
                $formStateManager = $this->formStateManager;
                $formState = $formStateManager->findOneById(intval($formStateId));

                // Choosen FormState data
                $formStateData = $formState->getData();

                $event->setData($formStateData); // <-- Call setData() on the FormEvent, not on the form itself
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure this solution will save someone days of coding!